# Websocket issue preventing bokeh app deployed in heroku from loading in website

Tags: heroku, bokeh

I have a bokeh app deployed in heroku. I want to embed it in a website, but am failing to do so.

The app is here:

https://ckgsb-final.herokuapp.com/cn_ckgsb

And this is for the script to use in the website:

```
from bokeh.embed import server_document

script = server_document("https://ckgsb-final.herokuapp.com/cn_ckgsb")

print(script)

<script id="1014">
  (function() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.open('GET', "https://ckgsb-final.herokuapp.com/cn_ckgsb/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=1014&bokeh-app-path=/cn_ckgsb&bokeh-absolute-url=https://ckgsb-final.herokuapp.com/cn_ckgsb", true);
    
    xhr.onload = function (event) {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      const src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.response);
      script.src = src;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    };
    xhr.send();
  })();
</script>
```

The procfile for the heroku app is:

```
web: bokeh serve --port=$PORT --allow-websocket-origin=ckgsb-final.herokuapp.com --address=0.0.0.0 --use-xheaders cn_ckgsb.py
```

I know the problem is with the websocket. I've tried various combinations of the app url in both the procfile and the script code, but haven't managed to fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure an allowed websocket origin for the URL of the embedding site as well. When users navigate to *mysite.org* and the page there tries to embed the Bokeh app, the HTTP origin received by the Bokeh server will be *mysite.org*. If the Bokeh server has not been configured to allow that origin, the request will be rejected.

Comment: Thanks. Just so I am clear, this should be in the file setting up the app.....so if the website I am using to embed is mysite.org, then I should make the procfile in my app directory show `--allow-websocket-origin=ckgsb-final.herokuapp.com --allow-websocket-origin=mysite.org`

Comment: It depends on what you intend. Including the first one will also allow users to navigate directly to the app at the heroku URL. If that's what you intend, then yes.